# PHP mobile detection script

Tags: php, mobile, detect

I came across this really simple mobile detection function in another SO question.  However, I cannot get it to work.

I am putting the function in the PHP code followed up by a call to the function.

However, it is returning the following error.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF in web...index.php on line 11 on line 11
```

Can anyone spot what I am doing wrong in code beow?  Thanks in advance for any ideas!

`index.php`:

```
<?php
    function checkMobile() {
        if (preg_match("/Mobile|Android|BlackBerry|iPhone|Windows Phone/",$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))
        {
            header("Location:mobile/index.php");
        }
    }
    checkMobile()
?>
```

Comment: Try this library instead: http://mobiledetect.net/

Comment: In terms of your question, do you have line 11 pasted in your question?

Comment: line 11 is one of those lines above.  I think line 11 is literally checkMobile() however it is triggering the function.  When I take checkMobile() out, the page loads without issue.  Only when including call to function do I get T_IF error

Comment: mobiledetect looks like a robust way to go but I'd just like to get this simple script working

Comment: Hmm, yeah, I can't see any obvious errors in that if statement. Strange.

Comment: Maybe add a semi-colon after checkMobile() ?

Comment: That fixed above error.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe, because you forgot the `;` after `CheckMobile()`

`CheckMobile() -> CheckMobile();`